# Using read.csv.sql to select multiple values from a single column

Tags: r, sqldf

I am using `read.csv.sql` from the package `sqldf` to try and read in a subset of rows, where the subset selects from multiple values - these values are stored in another vector.

I have hacked a way to a form that works but I would like to see the correct way to pass the `sql` statement.

Code below gives minimum example.

```
library(sqldf)

# some data
write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

# values to select from variable 'carb'
cc <- c(1, 2)

# This only selects last value from 'cc' vector
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = paste("select * from file where carb = ", cc ))

# So try using the 'in' operator - this works
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = "select * from file where carb in (1,2)" ) 

# but this doesn't
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = paste("select * from file where carb in ", cc ))

# Finally this works
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = paste("select * from file where carb in ", 
                                       paste("(", paste(cc, collapse=",") ,")")))
```

The final line above works, but is there are cleaner way to pass this statement, thanks.

Comment: Can't think of a cleaner way. That's what I routinely do when I face this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) fn$** Substitution can be done with `fn$` of gsubfn (which is automatically pulled in by sqldf).  See the `fn$` examples on the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com).  In this case we have:

```
fn$read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", 
  sql = "select * from file where carb in ( `toString(cc)` )")
```

**2) join** Another approach would be to create a data.frame of the `carb` values desired and perform a join with it:

```
Carbs <- data.frame(carb = cc)
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = "select * from Carbs join file using (carb)")
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Gabor; I had gone through your home page but did not pick up on using the `fn$` method - ill spend a bit of time to try an understand it. Your second method is more the sql magic i was expecting. Does this still result in only the selected rows being read in by R (I am working with a quite large dataset)?

Comment: Yes, mtcars.csv and Carbs are read into sqlite, the join is done there and only the result is read back into R.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `deparse`, but I'm not sure it's much cleaner than what you already have:

```
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv",
             sql = paste("select * from file where carb in ", gsub("c","",deparse(cc)) ))
```

And note that this is not really a general solution, because `deparse` will not always give you the right character string. It just happens to work in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. It is a bit cleaner although along the same lines. Your final sentence suggests that the `paste` method is safer? (although expecting another alternative / better method than paste for this)

Comment: @user2957945 Yes, this isn't going to generalize because `deparse` represents different vectors in different ways. It just happens to be that for the vector 1:2, it represents it in the way that you need.

Comment: I would never use `deparse`. See for instance the difference between `deparse(1:2)` and `deparse(c(1,2))`, even if the the argument is basically the same. Also, `deparse` can return a character vector longer than one (for example `deparse(c(1:100,101,102:200))`).

Comment: @nicola; thank you for the explanation - it shows some of the problems that i think Thomas was hinting at, but as I am not familiar with deparse,  i appreciate the example.