# Reading Column Names and Column Values for Extremely Large File R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, large-data

I need to load a CSV file in RStudio 3 (on Mac) which is ~11GB; this makes it impossible to load using regular commands. I need a subset of this data based on certain column values which should make it manageable. How can I:

1. get the column names without loading the entire file as a dataframe
2. read a single column from this file as a list

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how many columns the data have? And the type of data, character, numeric, what?

Comment: See function `read.csv.sql` in package `sqldf` to read just one column.

Comment: Check out `vroom` or `data.table` packages mentioned in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542. I would read only the first line to parse column name, then read selected columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.

### 1. Column names

The column names are read with `reaLines`, setting `n = 1`, in order to read just the columns headers line. Then `scan` with `sep = ","` will break the line into column names.

```
library(sqldf)

col_names <- readLines(tmpfile, n = 1)
col_names
#[1] "mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb"

tc <- textConnection(col_names)
col_names <- scan(tc, sep = ",", what = character())
close(tc)
```

### 2. Data

The 4th column is `"hp`. Read only that one with `read.csv.sql`. The SQL statement is put together with `sprintf`.

```
col_names[4]
#[1] "hp"

SQL <- sprintf("select %s from file", col_names[4])
SQL
#[1] "select hp from file"

hp <- read.csv.sql(tmpfile, sql = SQL)
str(hp)
#'data.frame':  6718464 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ hp: int  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
```

Comment: would this also work for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663085/extract-data-from-large-xml-using-r ?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen No, `sqldf` cannot parse XML.