# R - reading large csv files (e.g. 8 million rows and a few columns)

Tags: r

Having read explanation on this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes) ,I tried to read a large csv file containing 8 million rows and 26 columns with library feather and other libraries vroom, data.table etc. However, it gives me the same error:

> file = "file.feather" 
> write_feather(read_df, file) 
> new_df = read_feather(file) 
>  
> **ERROR: Cannot allocate vector of size 61.9 Mb**

I browsed around thereafter and found out that in such cases the memory size of R should be increased using memory.size(max = ....Mb). It did not resolve the issue, either.

Can someone explaine to me how to resolve such issues?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678940/how-to-deal-with-a-50gb-large-csv-file-in-r-language https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536226/r-reading-a-huge-csv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594639/how-do-i-import-a-large-6-gb-csv-file-into-r-efficiently-and-quickly-without

Comment: Thanks! I am going to check them all.